# How to retrieve the ARN from a SES template resource?

Tags: go, aws-cdk

I am working on a project where I need to send emails using AWS Lambda and Amazon Simple Email Service (SES). I'm using AWS CDK v2 with Golang for infrastructure provisioning and deployment. However, I'm facing difficulties in authorizing the Lambda function to send emails through SES. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this?

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/v2"
    "github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/v2/awsiam"
    "github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/v2/awsses"
    "github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdklambdagoalpha/v2"
    "github.com/aws/jsii-runtime-go"
)

func main() {
    app := awscdk.NewApp(nil)
    stack := awscdk.NewStack(app, nil, nil)

    template := awsses.NewCfnTemplate(stack, nil, nil)
    iamPolicy := awsiam.NewPolicyStatement(
        &awsiam.PolicyStatementProps{
            Actions:   jsii.Strings("ses:SendTemplatedEmail"),
            Resources: jsii.Strings( /* Extract the ARN from the template */ ),
        },
    )

    lambda := awscdklambdagoalpha.NewGoFunction(stack, nil, nil)
    lambda.AddToRolePolicy(iamPolicy)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A SES template ARN has the [form](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonsimpleemailservicev2.html#amazonsimpleemailservicev2-template):

```
arn:${Partition}:ses:${Region}:${Account}:template/${TemplateName}
```

`TemplateName` is set by you in the [template definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-personalized-email-api.html). You can either use string interpolation or the CDK [ARN helpers](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/v2#ArnComponents) to build the ARN.

Note:  See the [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon Simple Email Service v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonsimpleemailservicev2.html#amazonsimpleemailservicev2-template) docs for permissions required by the various send commands.